# Can entanglement witnesses on GHZ states with $n > 2$ violate the non-communication theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

In experiments involving entangled photons, measuring entanglement in systems with more than two particles ($n > 2$) often employs one photon as a herald to distinguish signal photons from noise. In a three-photon arrangement, for example, one photon serves as the herald, and entanglement is assessed using the remaining two.

However, entanglement in certain states, such as GHZ states, cannot be preserved if any constituent is measured in a non-orthogonal basis. So if the polarization of the heralding photon is measured before the others, entanglement between the remaining two photons is lost.

Entanglement quantified by violating the CHSH inequality is measured collectively over a large batch of individual measurements. So, by choosing whether or not to measure the batch of heralding photons, I can influence the CHSH calculation's outcome. If measured, the remaining photons will not exhibit entanglement; if not, they will.

It may seem like just semantics, but the no-communication theorem addresses individual measurements and states rather than the overall correlations demonstrated by entanglement. So, can the presence of entanglement itself rather than any particular state be used to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

For each individual photon in the GHZ state, the expectation values of each measurement are unaffected by measurements on any of the others. The only way to tell if the remaining two photons in the GHZ set are entangled after one of them is measured is to compare the measurement results. Since breaking the entanglement doesn't cause communication the non-communication theorem still holds.

It is common for people to say that quantum mechanics is non-local, but Bell's theorem only prohibits realistic theories, i.e. - theories in which each measurable quantity is described by a stochastic variable, from being local and reproducing Bell correlations. Quantum theory isn't realistic inn this sense since it describes physical quantities in terms of Hermitian operators, not stochastic variables. The evolution of those observables is local since the equations of motion for real quantum systems are local, and so information can only get from one system to another by propagating locally. For more details see

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

Comment: The first paragraph is fine. The rest is simply a recitation of key concepts of the Many Worlds Interpretation of QM. None of that is mainstream physics. All of the references are defenses of the MWI one way or another by advocate David Deutsch (and co-authors). The mainstream view is that quantum nonlocality has been demonstrated experimentally. The Nobel Committee said as much when awarding Zeilinger the Nobel in 2022. "...his research group has demonstrated a phenomenon called quantum teleportation, which makes it possible to move a quantum state from one particle to one at a distance."

Comment: @DrChinese Your comment makes no arguments about the substance of the issues involved so it is irrelevant.

Comment: The substance is that MWI is not mainstream physics. Your references and related commentary should be deleted.

Comment: @DrChinese If you have another account of precisely how entanglement correlations arise you could post your own answer.

Comment: I already posted an answer to the original question, which was not about how entanglement is created. But here are 3 somewhat dated summaries of work on Bell, entanglement, GHZ, etc that touch on almost anything/everything around this. MWI is not mentioned anywhere, because it is not now - nor has it ever been - mainstream. Zeilinger (1999 approx. 75 references): https://courses.washington.edu/ega/more_papers/zeilinger.pdf Genovese (2007, 106 pages, 505 references): https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0701071 Cavalcanti et al (2008, approx. 300 references): https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.0270

Comment: The first and third references don't explain any specific mechanism by which the correlations could arise. The second is about hidden variable theories, which say QM is false and should be replaced by another as yet undefined theory which would have to throw out not only QM but also Lorentz invariance. It is unclear how you can regard as mainstream a theory that doesn't currently exist and contradicts all of our most fundamental theories while discarding the MWI which doesn't contradict quantum theory or any other fundamental physical theory.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points: In traditional N=3 GHZ or W entangled systems, none are really operating as the "herald".  Production of such a GHZ state can, however, come from an N=4 system in which one is treated as the herald (leaving 3 entangled).

In the GHZ state, you have |000> + |111> to start with. After measuring any 1 of the 3, you know the values of the other 2. They are not entangled though, and will not violate CHSH. Keep in mind that order of measurement is completely irrelevant. None can be specifically identified as causing loss of entanglement other than by assumption. Importantly, there is no scenario in which 2 of the 3 photons will violate CHSH - even if you send the 3rd off into space.

In the W state, you have |100> + |010> + |001> to start with. After measuring any of the 3, you won't know the values of the other 2. They are still entangled though.

To tie the GHZ back to your point "Entanglement quantified by violating the CHSH inequality is measured collectively over a large batch of individual measurements."  Actually, in the GHZ state, there is no need to measure over a group of trials to determine if there is GHZ entanglement.  In an ideal setup, only 1 trial is required. This is one of the most important aspects of GHZ.  Certain specific (but different) measurements made on the 3 will indicate immediately if the GHZ is present or not. That's because the results are precisely opposite if they were in the GHZ state versus if they were in a Product State (and therefore not entangled).

The proof of this is complicated, much more so than the Bell proof.  Below is a great reference (from the Z in GHZ), but explains all this in more detail than you would probably ever want LOL. It includes discussion of N=3 and N=4 states.  Of course in actual scientific experiments, one trial would never be enough and no setup is truly ideal. Figure 16.6 shows the ideal predictions for entangled (quantum) states, the ideal predictions for the unentangled (local realistic) states, and the actual experimental results (showing entanglement to 8 standard deviations).

https://www.drchinese.com/David/Bell-MultiPhotonGHZ.pdf

Comment: Yes, GHZ rather than W because W is resilient to loss. I'm using the word "batch" the same way the article uses the term "trial."

But if only two are measured and the third is not the two will still be entangled and still exhibit non-classical correlations, right? Only |HH> or |VV>, hardly ever |HV> or |VH>.

Comment: @ScottStults For GHZ, yes and no. Generally, you are correct about |HH> or |VV>. Those should show perfect correlation. But the Bell inequalities come into play when pairs are measured at different angle settings. And those inequalities vary according to what happens to the 3rd photon. Although the wiki page may not be clear about this, you can get an idea of the situation from the section entitled Pairwise Entanglement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state (again keeping in mind there are a lot of moving parts in GHZ).

Comment: Thank you. I clarified the question by stipulating that the third photon is measured in a non-orthogonal basis.